# Android SQLite No such table?

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite

I have created a method

```
public boolean addWord(Word w, String name) {
    try {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(COLUMN_NAME, name);
        cv.put(COLUMN_WORD_FOREIGN, w.getWordForeign());
        cv.put(COLUMN_WORD_ENGLISH, w.getWordEnglish());
        cv.put(COLUMN_CORRECT, w.getCorrect());
        database.insert(TABLE_VOCAB_WORDS, null, cv);
        return true;
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        System.out.println("SQL ERROR");
        return false;
    }
}
```

But whenever I call it, I am getting a table not found error. However, the SQL statement that I use to create the database is as follows :

```
private static final String CREATE_DB = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_VOCAB_INFO
        + "(" + COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY," + COLUMN_URL
        + " TEXT NOT NULL," + COLUMN_DOWNLOADED
        + " TEXT NOT NULL); CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_VOCAB_WORDS + "("
        + COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL," + COLUMN_WORD_FOREIGN
        + " TEXT NOT NULL," + COLUMN_WORD_ENGLISH + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
        + COLUMN_CORRECT + " BYTE NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (" + COLUMN_NAME
        + "," + COLUMN_WORD_FOREIGN + "));";
```

As I am clearly creating the table, I'm not quite sure what error is actually happening
 here?

Any suggestions?

Comment: `COLUMN_CORRECT + "BYTE NOT NULL...` you need a <space> before `BYTE`

Comment: 1/ post stacktrace. 2/ check log when creating the table. 3/ adb shell and sqlite3 to look into your database. 4/ i don't think creating 2 tables in one query works. 5/ i'd add a space between table name and (. 6/ your second table lacks a ) 7/ clearly you are not creating the table.

Comment: also "I am clearly creating the table", while your not, doesn't give a very good image.

Comment: I have added the ) yet it doesn't work

Comment: did you split `CREATE_DB` into two separate `CREATE_xxx` statements? i don't know if multiple CREATES in a statement will work...i've never seen it done. did you fix the `COLUMN_CORRECT` problem?

Comment: Yes I did. I'll try it in multiple statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think reason why this not working is `;` This char is not allowed. So try to do it with two separated `Strings` so:

```
String create_vocal_table_info_query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_VOCAB_INFO
        + "(" + COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,"
        + COLUMN_URL + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
        + COLUMN_DOWNLOADED + " TEXT NOT NULL)";

String create_vocal_table_words_query = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_VOCAB_WORDS + "("
        + COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
        + COLUMN_WORD_FOREIGN + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
        + COLUMN_WORD_ENGLISH + " TEXT NOT NULL,"
        + COLUMN_CORRECT + " BYTE NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY ("
        + COLUMN_NAME + "," + COLUMN_WORD_FOREIGN + "))";
```

Comment: Thanks, saved my ass. I had a long CREATE statement that created a lot of tables. That was working fine on previous API level (I think it was 2.2) but stopped working on 3.0